# All real functions such that $(x+y)(f(x) - f(y)) = (x - y)f(x + y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Find all functions $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $(x + y)(f(x) - f(y)) = (x - y)f(x + y), \forall x,y \in \mathbb R$

Rearranging we get $$\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y} = \frac{f(x + y)}{x + y}$$ which is just the slope of the graph of $f$ equated to it's output divided by it's input. I don't know what term you give for $\frac{output}{input}$, but I guess the answer can be found this way. How do I continue?

Comment: As for the geometrical interpretation you mention: since $f(0) = 0$ we have $\frac{f(x+y)}{x+y} = \frac{f(x+y) - f(0)}{(x+y) - 0}$ so the equation says that the slope over the interval $[x,y]$ is the same as the slope over the interval $[0,x+y]$.

Comment: Just wanted to know, how did you derive that $f(0) = 0$

Comment: @Helix: try $y=-x$ and you get $f(0)=0$

Comment: So all functions with order 2 will satisfy the condition if $x+y=0$. What about other cases for $x,y$?

Comment: @Helix: using $y=-2x$ we can obtain that $f(x)=-f(-2x)/2$. Not sure if this helps.

Comment: @Vasya: It just gives a set of linear functions, which are already included if we take $x+y = 0$

Comment: If you substitute a power series for $f$ (assuming it has one) and start canceling stuff, it comes out pretty fast that $f$ is of the form $ax+bx^2.$  If it doesn't have a power series, then....?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ satisfy the equation. By setting $(x,y)$ to be $(t,1)$, $(t+1,1)$ and $(t,2)$ we get:
\begin{align}
(t-1)f(t+1)&=(t+1)(f(t)-f(1))\\
tf(t+2)&=(t+2)(f(t+1)-f(1))\\
(t-2)f(t+2)&=(t+2)(f(t)-f(2))
\end{align} 
By eliminating $f(t+2)$ by using the second and the third equation, and then eliminating $f(t+1)$ by using the first one, I got:
$$f(t)= t(2-t)f(1)+\frac{t(t-1)}{2}f(2).$$

Consider for $a,b\in\mathbb R$ the function: $$F_{a,b}(t)=t(2-t)a+\frac{t(t-1)}{2}b.$$ By the above, if $f$ satisfies the given equation we have that $f=F_{f(1),f(2)}$. On the other hand, one can directly check (I did) that the functions $F_{a,b}$ satisfy the given equation. So the answer is $\{F_{a,b}\mid a,b\in\mathbb R\}$.

Comment: Great answer! I guess the intuition lied in checking how the function behaved for adjacent points. Thanks!